# Spring MVC behavior while co-existing with traditional web app servlets

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc

We have an existing application not using Spring MVC. We decided to keep existing features as is and add Spring MVC in for any other new features through a url like "/admin/*.

so here is the web.xml mapping:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springRouted</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>4</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springRouted</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>ExistingServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>existing.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here in the ExistingServlet, there is a call to request.getRequestDispatcher().forward("/admin/...jsp"), somehow Spring will detect this fowarding and report an error that not able to find mapping for "/admin/...jsp". It seems calling request.getRequestDispatcher().forward("/admin/...jsp") will make servlet container to recheck the web.xml and reroute through Spring's DispatchServlet. is it true? I thought this kind of internal forward won't be intercepted by Spring's DispatchServlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `RequestDispatcher` will be resolved against the mappings you have in your deployment descriptor (web.xml) or other `Servlet` configuration, basically all servlet mappings.

When you do

```
 request.getRequestDispatcher("/admin/...jsp");
```

The `Servlet` container finds the `Servlet` (or other resource) meant to handle that path and wraps it in a `RequestDispatcher` object. When you then perform `RequestDispatcher#forward(..)` on the returned object, you are executing the `service()` method of the `Servlet` that was previously found.

In your example, that would be the `DispatcherServlet`. If your `DispatcherServlet` is configured to handle a request to `/admin/...jsp`, then it will do so. If not, it will throw its own custom exception, responding to the HTTP request with a 404.

[Here are some more details on how `getRequestDispatcher()` works.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619949/how-does-function-terminate-with-requestdispatcher-forward/19620731#19620731)